# Laurent series of $\frac{1}{z^4+z^2}$ about $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Okay, I get $\frac{1}{z^4+z^2}=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z^2+1}$

And I know I need to use geometric series sum but couldn't quite find it. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the two terms is easy $$\frac{1}{1+z^2} = \frac{1}{1-(-z^2)}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^mz^{2m}.$$ For the other, notice that $\frac{1}{z^2}$ is **already** in a Laurent form at $z=0.$ So the developpement is $$\frac{1}{z^4+z^2} = \frac{1}{z^2} - \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^mz^{2m}.$$

Comment: I don't know if your answer is correct but I got the answer now. We shouldnt do partial fractions here.


$\frac{1}{z^4+z^2}=\frac{1}{z^2(1-(-z^2))}=\frac{1}{z^2}.\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^mz^{2m}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^mz^{2m-2}$

Maybe your answer is correct but this forms is better I think.

Comment: My answer is exactly the same. :) You can write the first terms to be convinced.

Comment: Ah yes, then I delete my answer and leave my comment so that people see both writing.